# Using Spring JPA to setup a Aggregate Function for STRING_AGG with Postgresql for a Group_By

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, aggregate-functions

I am trying to setup a `repository` call to retrieve the ID's of a list of test results `ids` used in the `GROUP_BY`.  I can get this to work using `createNativeQuery` but I am unable to get this to work using Spring's `JPA` with the `FUNCTION` call.

```
FUNCTION('string_agg', FUNCTION('to_char',r.id, '999999999999'), ',')) as ids
```

I am using Spring Boot 1.4, hibernate and PostgreSQL.

**Question**

1. If someone can please help me out to setup the proper function call
   shown below in the JPA example it would be much appreciated.

**Update 1**

After implementing the custom dialect it looks like its trying to cast the function to a `long`.  Is the Function code correct?

```
FUNCTION('string_agg', FUNCTION('to_char',r.id, '999999999999'), ','))
```

**Update 2**

After looking into the dialect further it looks like you need to register the return type for your function otherwise it will default to a `long`.  See below for a solution.

**Here is my code:**

DTO

```
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class TestScriptErrorAnalysisDto {
        private String testScriptName;
        private String testScriptVersion;
        private String checkpointName;
        private String actionName;
        private String errorMessage;
        private Long count;
        private String testResultIds;
    }
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Set<TestScriptErrorAnalysisDto>> getTestScriptErrorsByExecutionId(@RequestParam("executionId") Long executionId) throws Exception {

    return new ResponseEntity<Set<TestScriptErrorAnalysisDto>>(testScriptErrorAnalysisRepository.findTestScriptErrorsByExecutionId(executionId), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Repository trying to use Function **Not working**

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT new com.dto.TestScriptErrorAnalysisDto(r.testScriptName, r.testScriptVersion, c.name, ac.name, ac.errorMessage, count(*) as ec, FUNCTION('string_agg', FUNCTION('to_char',r.id, '999999999999'), ',')) "
    + "FROM Action ac, Checkpoint c, TestResult r " + "WHERE ac.status = 'Failed' " + "AND ac.checkpoint = c.id " + "AND r.id = c.testResult " + "AND r.testRunExecutionLogId = :executionId "
    + "GROUP by r.testScriptName, r.testScriptVersion, c.name, ac.name, ac.errorMessage " + "ORDER by ec desc")
Set<TestScriptErrorAnalysisDto> findTestScriptErrorsByExecutionId(@Param("executionId") Long executionId);
```

Repository using createNativeQuery **working**

```
    List<Object[]> errorObjects = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
            "SELECT r.test_script_name, r.test_script_version, c.name as checkpoint_name, ac.name as action_name, ac.error_message, count(*) as ec, string_agg(to_char(r.id, '999999999999'), ',') as test_result_ids "
                    + "FROM action ac, checkpoint c, test_result r " + "WHERE ac.status = 'Failed' " + "AND ac.checkpoint_id = c.id "
                    + "AND r.id = c.test_result_id " + "AND r.test_run_execution_log_id = ? "
                    + "GROUP by r.test_script_name, r.test_script_version, c.name, ac.name, ac.error_message " + "ORDER by ec desc")
    .setParameter(1, test_run_execution_log_id).getResultList();

    for (Object[] obj : errorObjects) {
        for (Object ind : obj) {
            log.debug("Value: " + ind.toString());
            log.debug("Value: " + ind.getClass());
        }
    }
```

Here was the documents I found on FUNCTION

```
            4.6.17.3 Invocation of Predefined and User-defined Database Functions

    The invocation of functions other than the built-in functions of the Java Persistence query language is supported by means of the function_invocation syntax. This includes the invocation of predefined database functions and user-defined database functions.

     function_invocation::= FUNCTION(function_name {, function_arg}*)
     function_arg ::=
             literal |
             state_valued_path_expression |
             input_parameter |
             scalar_expression
    The function_name argument is a string that denotes the database function that is to be invoked. The arguments must be suitable for the database function that is to be invoked. The result of the function must be suitable for the invocation context.

    The function may be a database-defined function or a user-defined function. The function may be a scalar function or an aggregate function.

    Applications that use the function_invocation syntax will not be portable across databases.

    Example:

    SELECT c
    FROM Customer c
    WHERE FUNCTION(‘hasGoodCredit’, c.balance, c.creditLimit)
```

Comment: Is this a typo `FUNCTION('string_agFUCNTIONTION('to_char',r.id, '999999999999'), ','))` ??

Comment: @JorgeCampos          Yes it was, I have updated it but it seems to be not working still.

Comment: "does not work". Wonder what that means

Comment: @DN1            "Does not work", is described above with the issue that it is trying to put FUNCTION('string_agg', FUNCTION('to_char',r.id, '999999999999'), ',')) into a long and not a string.

Comment: So raise a BUG on your chosen JPA provider. Your JPQL is perfectly valid, and it is for the JPA provider to handle the mapping into that the constructor expression

Comment: @DN1           It turns out when doing the registration for the function in the dialect you need to set your appropriate return type.

Comment: The JPA spec does not require that, so you've just become vendor specific due to your JPA vendor not providing such things out of the box. Other providers don't need that; the return type of the SQL function can be seen on extraction of results so there is no real reason why a JPA provider would need that (other than not bothering checking the results and imposing it on the user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the main piece which was missing was defining the functions by creating a new class to extend the PostgreSQL94Dialect.   Since these functions were not defined for the dialect they were not processed in the call.

```
    public class MCBPostgreSQL9Dialect extends PostgreSQL94Dialect {

        public MCBPostgreSQL9Dialect() {
            super();
            registerFunction("string_agg", new StandardSQLFunction("string_agg", new org.hibernate.type.StringType()));
            registerFunction("to_char", new StandardSQLFunction("to_char"));
            registerFunction("trim", new StandardSQLFunction("trim"));
        }
    }
```

The other issue was that a type needed to be set for the return type of the function on registration.  I was getting a `long` back because by default `registerFunction` returns a `long` even though string_agg would return a string in a sql query in postgres.

After updating that with `new org.hibernate.type.StringType()` it worked.

```
            registerFunction("string_agg", new StandardSQLFunction("string_agg", new org.hibernate.type.StringType()));
```

Comment: How to register 'string_agg' function for microsoft sql (mssql) ?