# Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have a custom created function in postgres , now i'm trying to call the custom method from my code. here is the repository function

```java
    @Query(value = "select function('createCluster',:tName,:time,:iPattern)")
    boolean createClusterIndex(@Param("tName") String tableName, @Param("iPattern") String indexPattern, @Param("time") LocalDateTime time);
```

going from this link
https://thorben-janssen.com/database-functions/

i even registered by function in postgres dialect

```
this.registerFunction("createcluster",new StandardSQLFunction("createCluster",new BooleanType()));
```

but once i run the code

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: 'function (createCluster)'
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'createCluster' {originalText=createCluster}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       +-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=tName, expectedType=null}
       +-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=time, expectedType=null}
       \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=iPattern, expectedType=null}

    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:161) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:1018) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:786) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:677) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
    ... 106 common frames omitted
```

what could be the cause of this? how can i resolve this?

questions i have gone through:

[Using Spring JPA to setup a Aggregate Function for STRING_AGG with Postgresql for a Group_By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47878811/using-spring-jpa-to-setup-a-aggregate-function-for-string-agg-with-postgresql-fo)

[No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode HQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471534/no-data-type-for-node-org-hibernate-hql-internal-ast-tree-identnode-hql)

[Write & Call user-defined function in JPQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647582/write-call-user-defined-function-in-jpql)

[User defined PostgreSQL function in hibernate dialect throws exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62567915/user-defined-postgresql-function-in-hibernate-dialect-throws-exception)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a native query. `@Query(value = "select createCluster(:tName,:time,:iPattern)", nativeQuery = true`

Comment: i want avoid using native query

Comment: Avoiding the native query doesn't buy you anything as this is a database specific function I suppose? Anyway, you can avoid that by also adding a FROM clause to the query. Hibernate requires a FROM clause.

Comment: a custom function is part of almost every RDBMS Db , but i'm not sure about No-Sql , also the links i added are all indicating that it should be possible. finally i did try the FROM part , but it did not work either